# Django iterate zip from same position in lists

Tags: python, django

first I zip all my lists just like

```
 books= zip(*bookName, *detail)
```

the length of bookbName and detail is same,
and I want to get the table like

```
  {% for bookName, detail, in books %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{bookName}}</td>
                <td>{{detail}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

As I can not confirm the length of bookName and detail, I got the error message like "Need 3 values to unpack in for loop; got 5. "

I tried

```
{% for record in books %}
  <tr>
    {% for item in record %}
      <td>{{ item }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

but the result is get detail after all the bookname show.
How can I get the table when I got first bookname then I can get the first book's detail?

for example the input list is

```
bookname: ["a", "b"]
detail:["fiction", "action"]
```

I want to get to table like

```
bookname  detail
  a        fiction
  b        action
```

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected output of the lists mentioned here ie. bookname and detail?

Comment: Shouldn't `books= zip(bookName, detail)` instead of `books= zip(*bookName, *detail)`

Comment: @JPG Exactly! thats what i was thinking. bookName could be list of lists.Z.L , If not you do not have to put * over there

Comment: @JPG Thank you for your answer, without the * I just can get the list like bookname: ["a", "b"].  detail["fiction","action"]. But what I want to show is <tr>a</tr><tr>fiction</tr>, then in the next loop <tr>b</tr><tr>action</tr>

Comment: Once that issue is solved, I _think_ the extra comma after `detail` in this line `{% for bookName, detail, in books %}` will cause issues and is the source of the `3` in `Need 3 values to unpack` instead of the expected `2`.

Comment: thank you @azundo. But in my situation the bookName and detail is variable, I can not sure the exact number of list.

Comment: Yep! That's fine. You will have a list of some unknown length, but each element of that list will itself be of length 2. With the extra comma in your original template code, it is trying to pull out 3 elements from each list item instead of only two. I think the answer below explains it more completely though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this clears your doubt and query:

```
bookname = ["a", "b"]
detail = ["fiction", "action"]

books1 = zip(bookname, detail)
print(list(books1))

# OUTPUT:
# [('a', 'fiction'), ('b', 'action')]

books2 = zip(*bookname, *detail)
print(list(books2))

# OUTPUT:
# [('a', 'b', 'f', 'a')]
```

Results after running for loop:

```
bookname = ["a", "b"]
detail = ["fiction", "action"]

books1 = zip(bookname, detail)

for name1, det1 in books1:
    print(name1, det1)

# OUTPUT:
# a fiction
# b action

books2 = zip(*bookname, *detail)

for name2, det2 in books2:
    print(name2, det2)

# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

EDIT:

HTML:

```
  {% for bookName, detail in books1 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{bookName}}</td>
                <td>{{detail}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. You let me know the zip more clear. But what I am confusing is I can not show the table you showed in the books1 in django template. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Im not sure what your code is... are you able to access "books" in your html template?

Comment: @Neeraj add the html from OP's question that begins with `{% for bookName, detail, in books %}` to your answer but remove that extra `,` after `detail`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ah! yes.. im hoping he can access books in the template

Comment: @Neeraj Your answer is helpful. But I got the list in one column, how could I split the value of list in difference columns?

Comment: @Z.L column1 should have bookname and column2 should have details according to the tr and td applied. td does split them in different columns whats the issue? can you share your html and output using pastebin? : https://pastebin.com/